# Get Stack Overflow questions with Stacky API

Tags: c#, stackexchange-api, stacky

I want to get the most current questions from *Stack Overflow* using the [Stacky C# library](https://stackapps.com/questions/6/stacky-a-net-client-library-full-support-for-api-v2-0) for the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/).

I took the example code and tried to run it but it hangs when it comes to returning data from the *Stack Exchange* website.

```
StackyClient client = new StackyClient("0.9", "", Sites.StackOverflow, 
            new UrlClient(), new JsonProtocol());

var o = new QuestionOptions();
o.FromDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10.0);
o.ToDate = DateTime.Now;
o.IncludeAnswers = false;
o.IncludeBody = false;
o.IncludeComments = false;
o.SortBy = QuestionSort.Creation;
o.SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;

IPagedList<Question> l = client.GetQuestions(o); <--- program hangs here 4ever
```

What am I doing wrong?

I also saw that I can [register my application](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) to get an *API Key*. But that is not necessary to make it run in the first place, is it?

### Edit

If I remove the lines

```
o.FromDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10.0);
o.ToDate = DateTime.Now;
```

it works and returns **all** questions. Also if I add the line

```
o.Max = 50;
```

instead, then it does not work either.

### Edit 2

Now it works - **rebooted my computer**.
BTW I used that code in the end

```
var o = new QuestionOptions();
o.FromDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-20);
o.IncludeAnswers = false;
o.IncludeBody = false;
o.IncludeComments = false;
o.SortBy = QuestionSort.Creation;
o.SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;

IPagedList<Question> l = client.GetQuestions(o);
```

And

```
o.Max
```

expects an Unix Epoch time, not a number of maximum posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the version specified in the `StackyClient` constructor from "0.9" to "1.1".  I get a JSON parse error on the `client.GetQuestions(o)` line when the version is "0.9", but it runs fine with "1.1".

Comment: Then it does not hang any more but the result does not contain any questions either.

Comment: Which version of the Stacky library are you using?  I downloaded the binary for v1.1 from codeplex [here](http://stacky.codeplex.com/releases/view/60851).  Other than changing the version and adding a loop to print question titles to a console window, my code is identical to yours, and it retrieves questions every time I run it.

Comment: I downloaded that version and also tried compiling the source code myself.

Comment: What time zone are you in?  Perhaps your requested from/to dates are in the future relative to SO's servers.

Comment: Argentinian time zone. But I tried a date in the past days and it does not work either.

Comment: I created my own UrlClient class to intercept and print the `Uri` the client is sending and got [this link](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions/?key=&fromdate=1367228893&todate=1367229493&sort=creation&order=desc)  Try pasting it into a browser and see if you get a response.  I get the expected json response if I view it in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest Stacky code from  [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/lfoust/stacky) there is no longer a QuestionOptions parameter to GetQuestions. Also using version 0.9 of the API causes Stacky to crash, but according to [this](http://api.stackexchange.com/) version 1.x is deprecated, so maybe 0.9 is removed?

```
  StackyClient client = new StackyClient("2.1", Sites.StackOverflow,
        new UrlClient(), new JsonProtocol());
  //var o = new QuestionOptions();
  //o.FromDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10.0);
  //o.ToDate = DateTime.Now;
  //o.IncludeAnswers = false;
  //o.IncludeBody = false;
  //o.IncludeComments = false;
  //o.SortBy = QuestionSort.Creation;
  //o.SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
  QuestionSort sort = QuestionSort.Creation;
  SortDirection sortDir = SortDirection.Descending;
  int page = 1;
  int pageSize = 100;
  DateTime fromDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10.0);
  DateTime toDate = DateTime.Now;
  IPagedList<Question> l = client.GetQuestions(sort, sortDir, page, pageSize, fromDate, toDate);
  foreach (var question in l)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(question.Title);
  }
```

Or, just remove the date and see if you get any results.

```
  IPagedList<Question> l = client.GetQuestions(sort, sortDir, page, pageSize);//, fromDate, toDate);
  foreach (var question in l)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(question.Title);
  }
```